# Confused about the variable type of a hash variable in perl

Tags: arrays, list, perl, hash, scalar

I have created a hash from 2 arrays of same size. One arrays element is used as index and another's as value.
`for (my $ele=2;$ele<=$#array1;ele++) {$hash{$array1[$ele]}=$array2[$ele];}`
  when I print it with Dumper, it shows similar to following:

```
$VAR1={'key1'=>'""',
       'key2'=>'"0"',
       'key3'=>'"47.55789"',
       'key4'=> '""',
       'key5'=>'"78.5463"',
       'key6'=>'"0"',
       'key7'=>'""'  };
```

I need to compare the values to identify some keys. And I am failing to understand what kind of value my hash keys are pointing to. I tried, `foreach(@array2){ print ref($_);}` and it returns nothing 859 times (there are 861 elements in both arrays. I didn't want the first 2 elements). `looks_like_number($hash{$key})` fails. And `if ref($hash{$key}) eq 'ARRAY'` is not array.
I am new to perl. At the beginning I thought, the values are array of strings OR list of strings which are itself list? may be? I tried to loop over all kind of possibilities but failing. It prints the values perfectly but I need to compare them but I can't reach to the exact value. `empty string/0/>50/<50`. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Dumper output of array1 is similar to : 
`$VAR1='abc'; 
 $VAR2='ghy';
 $VAR3='njkio';
 $VAR4='mkol';`
Dumper output of array2:

```
$VAR1='""';
$VAR2='"0"';
$VAR3='"47.55789"';
$VAR4='""';
$VAR5='"78.5463"';
$VAR6='"0"';
$VAR7='""';  

foreach my $grp(keys %Austin){
  foreach my $val ($Austin{$grp}){
     if(looks_like_number($val)){print "String is a NUMBER\n";}
     else {print "string is Not a number\n";}
  }
}
```

the printout for this loop is string is not a number each time. I tried to understand the '"76.90"' value.

Comment: That can't be your Dumper output because hash keys are unique. That for loop doesn't look right either. You should include your actual code, copy and pasted if needed, not some random kind of but not quite what you're actually doing thing. But the keys and values are all plain scalars. `ref` returns an empty string because they're not references.

Comment: please try to produce a minmum example with actual code without your original private data .  the for looo doesn't look right but i cant confirm with your  dummy code pieces

Comment: No that wasn't dumper code. The keys were unique. I have edited the code. The loop works right as far as i can say from the output of my dumper. I have 2 equal sized arrays with different kind of datas. I need to find the association. Hence the hash. Now I want to identify keys whose values are <50. But I can't reach the values. they are NOT ARRAYS. NOT REFERENCE. Therefore they are scalars. but the "looks_like_number()" function fails. Which means they are values warped inside some other data structure. I thought value inside string. Then why ref() eq 'ARRAY' fails?

Comment: I have edited the code. the code is exactly the same with original data.

Comment: Please show an example of the content of `@array1` and `@array2`. From the the dumper output, it seems like the values are wrapped inside double quotes. It is difficult to tell why that happend without you showing more code

Comment: Again, as @Shawn said, that code can't compile -- it's `$hash{ $v1 = $v2 ; }` -- see that semicolon? That's not allowed and would exit with `syntax error`. Can you please show realistic code? /// What you show doesn't assign a value to a key but assigns one variable to another inside of a key, like my example above. So (w/o that illegal semicolon) you'd have no keys, or, if there was more code, perhaps all keys would be the value of the assignment (returned in Perl), and without a value. You want `$hash{$array1[$ele]} = $array2[$ele];` ... but then there are better ways

Comment: `my %h; for my $i (2..$#ary) { $h{$ary1[$i]} = $ary2[$i] }` or in one statement (if there's no error checking etc) `my %h = map { $ary1[$_], $ary2[$_] } 2..$#ary;`

Comment: I did exactly this. I just typed it wrong here. My bad. corrected. It's a simple C style array. and from the Dumper output, i can see the hash is created correctly.

Comment: Dumper output of array1 is similar to : $VAR1='abc'; $VAR2='ghy';$VAR3='njkio';

Comment: @HåkonHægland, EXACTLY! i have put the similar output of array 1 and array2 in the original question.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include some code that I can copy, paste, and test to see the same output you are seeing?

Comment: @GreenRoad-Dhaka The question is why did `@array2` get values wrapped in double quotes? How did you create `@array2`?

Comment: array1 array2 was created from a text file. text was created from a excel.I read the file row by row and created an array for each row. first row is array1. All the rest of the rows has values "0"/""/"34.890" in this format (inside double quote). which when i assign to arrays becomes ' "0" '/' " " ' /' "34.678" ' like this.

Comment: @GreenRoad-Dhaka Ok then a simple solution is to remove the quotes before inserting them into the array?

Comment: was thinking about that. :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland is there any simple way of doing that automatically? too much data to do it by hand. also prone to errors

Comment: @GreenRoad-Dhaka Yes of course you have to do it automatically :) For example if `$s = '"abc"'` then remove quotes by `$s =~ s/^"|"$//g`

Comment: Modified the array content. Problem solved! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you right.
Try this:

```
my %Austin = (
    "key1"    => '""',
    "key2"    => '"0"',
    "key3"    => '"47.55789"',
    "key4"    => '""',
    "key5"    => '"78.5463"',
    "key6"    => '"0"',
    "key7"    => '""'
);

foreach my $grp(keys %Austin){
    print $grp, "\n";
    foreach my $val ($Austin{$grp}){
        print $val, "\n";
        if($val =~ m/\d/){
            print "String is a NUMBER\n";
        } else { 
            print "string is Not a number\n";
        }
    }
}
```